# .NET Core Web API async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have to show category and total number of items in each category on a mobile app. The categories are synchronised in our local database but the the items in each category are present in vendors database. So to get the total number of items, a separate call is made to the vendor's database.

Currently, we made a Web API that first retrieves all the categories from the local database and lists it on the screen and then make another Web API call to get total number of items from the vendor's database in order to avoid a bit long waiting and updates the screen with the count for each category. (For some reason, retrieving total count from vendor's database takes little more time).

My question - is there a way to return categories and total items for each category one by one to the caller from the same Web API method so that screen could be updated as data returns?

Comment: Hi, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you have tried and explain how it's not working the way you want.

Comment: You can make the request to the vendor api from your backend code. This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: What is the code reading from the API? C# or Javascript? And what is the format of the data being returned by the API? JSON?

Comment: Who maintains the API that searches your customer's database?